# Следует ли ставить запятую?

Tags: пунктуация

Следует ли ставить запятую после «момент»? «В праздники Сильвана особое внимание уделяется детям, как наиболее уязвимой части общества, в наиболее уязвимый переходный момент(,) в природном и хозяйственно-культурном цикле».

Comment: "В... момент... в цикле" лучше заменить на "в... момент... цикла".

Answer (score 1):

*В праздники Сильвана особое внимание уделяется детям, как наиболее уязвимой части общества, в наиболее уязвимый переходный момент **в природном и хозяйственно-культурном цикле.***

Обстоятельственный оборот является несогласованным определением и **не обособляется,** так как не имеет уточняющего значения и входит в основной состав предложения.

В устной речи делается **произносительная** (не грамматическая пауза), которая не обозначается запятой.

Примечание. Повтор слова ***уязвимый*** нежелателен, можно заменить его прилагательным ***сложный***.